# Unwanted whitespace when touch is enabled in firefox Responsive Design Mode

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design, responsive

The following snippet works properly in my browser, until I open Responsive Design Mode on Firefox, where it places a white space at the bottom of the page:

[image]

The "bug" disappears if I disable touch simulation.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style="height: 100vh" src="https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Download-Full-HD-Wallpapers-1080p-Free-620x349.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

### Update 1:

I found out that I needed to add:

```css
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
```

styling to the image. However, I still don't understand why I have to set width to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few new solutions for mobile problems with View Heights.
The First is that you could try

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

My second solution requires a little more research.
Here are some of the properties I think you should try:

```
width: 100vmin
width: 100vamx
```

Also, you should try the properties above with `min-height: ;`

There are actually 24 viewport properties. Kyle from Web Dev Simplified explains it very well in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m6JOJLy5B0&t=364s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified).

Comment: `min-height: 100vh` does not solve the issue. You can check the updated question to see what helped.